# Getting the Variable for a chosen Application Apple Script

Tags: applescript

I want to do a simple AppleScript Script, that opens an App Chooser and gets the selected App.

```
choose application with prompt "Choose an App:"
```

So it opens a Window where I can choose an App. In the next line I do:

```
activate application "Safari"
```

How can I write it so it opens the SELECTED App?

like `activate application SelectedApp`

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
set theApp to choose application with prompt "Choose an App:"
tell theApp
    activate
end tell
```